# Windows - Find all images on an external hard drive

Tags: windows, image, explorer

I have an old hard drive containing multiple hard drive backups, so there are hundreds of thousands of unsorted files and folders.

So I have to sort it out and delete everything I don't need, the problem is that there are family photos, class photos, etc. (pretty much everywhere)

**How to locate (and even be able to view) all the photos in a folder or even on the entire hard drive ?**

With the windows file explorer, I tried this:
[image: search image]

But it doesn't give me any results even on folders full of photos

**Is it possible to do this with windows explorer on an external hard drive? Do you know simple software is quick to do this?**

Comment: Try setting up Indexing Service on the HDD. https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/windows-10-index-files-improve-search,5593.html

Answer (score 0):

If it has hundreds of thousands of unsorted files and folders then wait after sorting by pictures. The many files will slow the computer so it might take about an hour to load the pictures.

Comment: It instantly puts me that there is no result, I even created a simple folder containing 2 word file and an image to do a test but with the ``kind: = picture`` I have no result